# How can I move a file to a directory?

Tags: bash, mv

I just want to read from the keyboard the file's name and move it to another directory.

I have this in my mind :

```
ls

read a // the name of the file

pwd

read b //the name of the directory where I want to move the file or  the path :-?

mv $a $b
```

Can someone correct me ? How should I use the mv command in this case?

Comment: What you are doing is no better than `mv /path/to/source /path/to/destination` ..what new are you trying actually ?

Comment: I have a menu and when I press number 9 I want to move a file(it`s name read from the keyboard) to a directory(I want to read from the keyboard the path of that directory) so I could move the file to the directory...

Comment: Does the source file is in the current directory ?

Comment: yes ....that`s why I wrote first " ls " to see what I have in the current directory so I could read from the keyboard one of those files...

Comment: i have that menu in a .sh  and I used the command : mv "$a" $b ;;

Comment: but I dont know how to apelate that fuction....

Comment: I fixed the problem ty anyway..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in this case, simply `mv filename path/to/somewhere`, but in general, you probably need an intro to basic shell stuff. This looks reasonable:

http://linuxcommand.org/learning_the_shell.php

And `mv` and friends particular:

http://linuxcommand.org/lts0050.php